# How can I prevent MIME type from being set to application/force-download?

Tags: mime-types, content-disposition, kentico, getfiles, force-download

I am working on a Kentico (CMS) site. When retrieving a file using Kentico's GetFile.aspx, on staging PDFs correctly have a inline disposition, and on production they incorrectly have a attachment disposition. (Open in browser on staging, as desired, and are saved to disk in production, the problem). Code files are identical, so it must be a configuration problem, presumably in IIS or Kentico.

I have tried providing a disposition parameter to GetFile.aspx, but this fails because the MIME type is application/force-download (only happens on prod). I am not sure where this MIME type is coming from. It doesn't show up in IIS' MIME types list. The PDFs in Kentico's database have the correct (application/pdf).

Whatever is different between production and staging I can't find. If anyone has any ideas of what it might be, I would appreciate the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

you can always force disposition by adding disposition parameter to the query string, e.g.:

```
http://www.domain.tld/CMSPages/GetFile.aspx?nodeguid=blabla&lang=en-US&maxsidesize=600&disposition=inline
```

The possible values are "attachment" and "inline". The problem on production server you are describing can be caused by accessing the PDF from mobile device. In that case disposition is automatically set to attachment.